# HTML Table issue for email newsletter

Tags: html, css, electronic-direct-mail

I have coded up an EDM for email distribution and I'm having a slight rendering issue.

My question is, why is it rendering like that in Outlook and what can I do to fix it?

Also, if you look at it in the browser it's not quite right, mainly because I had to set a 9px bottom margin to `.l4`. Can someone recommend another way to go about this so it renders correctly cross browser and email client?

Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly are you using nested tables? Using nested tables for layout is (and always has been) a terrible idea. If tables are required (and I don't exactly see why), wouldn't a single table suffice?

Comment: Try to select all in browser window and paste inside outlook message..

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm going to edit as per your comments above.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonah Bishop, it is always a good idea to use nested tables in email marketing unless you use a flattened image. CSS is tripped out by many online email apps like hotmail and inline styles on divs are problematic with many clients. By problematic, I mean it is challenging to write inline styles that work well across all email clients.

What are you using to test your emails? If your email marketing platform doesn't provide a testing suite, http://www.emailonacid.com/ is a good option. http://litmus.com/ is another great option that works well with mailchimp. In fact mailchimp (fantastic service) enables you to use litmus from your account: http://blog.mailchimp.com/tag/litmus/

Some tips: http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails

This is a great resource too: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Just looking at your code. I can see that your nested tables ar a bit of a mess in this situation. Sorry @Jonah. I think you need to simplify this middle section.